# java.lang.Exception: Calling @react-native-community * Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, salesforce-mobile-sdk

-I am updating my Salesforce Mobile SDK from 10.2 to 11.0.1 while doing it i am getting this error .
-I have created a new project in which sdk is 11.0.1 when i am trying to add my packages which i am using then i am getting this below error messgae tried many solution but none of them are working.

java.lang.Exception: Calling `[myProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

I have resolved this issue by deleting the below line from build.gradle(app) and setting.gradle.

apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

But after this, i am getting this new error in my MainApplication.java-
**Cannot resolve the symbol 'PackageList'**
to solve this I have tried deleting the node module and adding a new node module.

can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

1.**Check JSON Files**: Verify syntax errors in package.json and SDK config files.

2.**Update Dependencies**: Use npm-check-updates to update packages.

3.**Clean npm Cache**: Run npm cache clean -f to clear cache.

4.**Node Version**: Confirm compatible Node.js version.

5.**SDK** Configuration: Validate Mobile SDK config files for format.

6.**Community** Help: Check GitHub repos and issue trackers.

> Blockquote

7.**Documentation**: Refer to Salesforce Mobile SDK documentation for updates.

8.**Debugging**: Add logs/debugger to pinpoint JSON parsing error.